# How to migrate functional component from flow to typescript in react native?

Tags: typescript, react-native, flowtype

I have this functional component in flow

```
// @flow

import Images from '../../Images'
import Styles from './IconStyles'

export type IconType = $Keys<typeof Images.icons>

export type IconProps = {
  type: IconType,
  style?: any,
}

const Icon = ({ type, style }: IconProps) => {
  return (
    <Image
      source={Images.icons[type]}
      style={[Styles.icon, style]}
    />
  )
}
```

I am trying to convert this to typescript. My progress so far is as below

```
import React from 'react'
import { Image } from 'react-native'
import Images from '../../Images'
import Styles from './IconStyles'

export type IconType = keyof typeof Images.icons

interface IconProps {
  type: IconType
  style?: any
}
const Icon = ({ type, style }: IconProps) => (
  <Image source={Images.icons[type]} style={[Styles.icon, style]} />
)

export default Icon
```

and the Images js file is something like this

```
const icons = {
  chevronDown: require('./Icons/chevron-down.png'),
  chevronRight: require('./Icons/chevron-right.png'),
  ...
}

export default {
  icons
}
```

can you peeps point me in the right direction? I know for a fact that my typescript is correct but i cannot see any of the icons in the app. I suspect it has something to do with the images.js file?

Answer (score 0):

I realised that I was not setting the size of the image. All I had to do was to

```
<Image
  source={AppIcons[type]}
  style={[Styles.icon, { height: 20, width: 20 }, style]}
/>
```